# How to start creating a ChatGPT conversation system like for any specific domain data (Judicial)?

Tags: training, open-ai, gpt

I have a sufficient amount of relevant data about my domain. It includes data in Oracle DB as of now. Could someone guide me in the right direction as a novice how do I choose the right tools and frameworks to deploy and with which model I need to integrate etc stuff to start developing a simple tool?